# Load wordpress from local context of external application (from within a function)

Tags: php, wordpress, external

If I want to use wordpress functions from an external app, I'd do as follows:

```
require_once('/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php');
$isLoggedIn = is_user_logged_in();
```

This works without problems. But I would like to load wordpress from within a function. Something like this:

```
function wpIsUserLoggedIn()
{
    global $wpdb; // Otherwise there are bunch of errors when including wp-load.php
    require_once('/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php');
    return is_user_logged_in(); // Always returns false
}
```

In this case is_user_logged_in() always returns false. What am I missing? Is there a way to load WP from within a function?

Comment: First, you can't use **global $wpdb** before including **wp-load.php** file. Second, Where do you call **wpIsUserLoggedIn()** function ? it is within WordPress ?

Comment: @Milap: Function wpIsUserLoggedIn() is defined and used in an external application, not within wordpress. If I don't use global $wpdb, I get bunch of errors when including wp-load.php.

Comment: Did you try to include **wp-load.php** at the top of your php page ? not within function body.

Comment: @Milap: Yes, if I load wp-load.php at global scope, everything works correctly. But I'm looking for a way to load it only on demand in specific function.. (if possible at all)

Comment: nope its not possible. WordPress doesn't allow it.